# How to import ion-rangeslider in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to use the ionRangeSlider plugin in Aurelia but am not sure how to make use of it.

https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues

I have jspm'd it into my project but how do I import it as well as call the one function that runs the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the exact package names for including `ion-rangesider` in your package.json:

```
jspm": {
   "dependencies": {
        ...
        "ion-rangeslider": "npm:ion-rangeslider@^2.1.3",
        "jquery": "npm:jquery@^2.2.3",
         ...
    }
}
```

Then you need to create your own custom element like:

```js
import {inject, noView} from 'aurelia-framework';
//import your dependencies
import $ from 'jquery';
import ionRangeSlider from 'ion-rangeslider';

@noView()
@inject(Element)
export class Slider {

    constructor(element){
        this.element = element; 
    }

    bind(){
        $(this.element).ionRangeSlider({min: 100, max: 1000, from: 550});
    }
}
```

And where you want to use your slider you have to write:

```html
<require from='./slider'></require> 
<require from="ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css"></require>
<require from="ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css"></require>
<slider></slider>
```

Normally you would put the `<require from="xxx.css"></require>` tags inside slider.html to ensure style encapsulation. In my example i put them where i wanted to use the slider because so i don´t needed to create a slider.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use the bootstrap popover.
I guess you should be able to do the same and calling `$("#example_id").ionRangeSlider();` from within the `bind` function
if you imported all resources

[image]

Comment: I don't follow.  Should I create a separate class as a wrapper around the library or is there a more defined example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ion-rangeslider first:

   npm install ion-rangeslider

   jspm install npm:ion-rangeslider
2. Create a custom attribute

   ```
   import {customAttribute, bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
   import {ionRangeSlider} from 'ion-rangeslider';    
   @customAttribute('rangeslider')
   @inject(Element)
   export class RangesliderCustomAttribute {
     //make your own options based on requirements
     options = { type: "single", min: 0, max: 100 };    
     constructor(element) {
       this.element = element;
     }
     attached() {
       $(this.element).ionRangeSlider(this.options).on('change', e => {
         fireEvent(e.target, 'input');
       });
     }

     detached() {
       $(this.element).ionRangeSlider('destroy').off('change');
     }
   }

   function createEvent(name) {
     var event = document.createEvent('Event');
     event.initEvent(name, true, true);
     return event;
   }

   function fireEvent(element, name) {
     var event = createEvent(name);
     element.dispatchEvent(event);
   }
   ```
3. import css into app.html or where you import css in your application

   ```
   <require from="ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css"></require>
   <require from="ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinNice.css"></require>
   ```
4. Now you can use your attribute in input in any view

   ```
   <require from="./rangeslider"></require>
   <input rangeslider type="text" value.bind="yourInitialSliderValue">
   ```