# Importing chart.js to aurelia causes page errors after bunldling

Tags: chart.js, aurelia

In a project using the aurelia framework I installed chart.js v2.0 beta using:

```
jspm install npm:chart.js
```

I import the library by using:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

When application is unbundled I get no errors. If I bundle the application the page loads and displays the graph, but I get 78 errors of missing javascript files like this:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/core/core.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4597
```

As far as I can think it searches for these files (which are part of the chart.js library), in the base directory (which is localhost:9000 as I run gulp watch).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don´t know if it will solve your Problem but you should say Aurelia that u want to use chart.js with `aurelia.use.plugin('chart')`. Maybe the name is not "chart". You have to take a look at your package.json. The right name will be the one under `jspm > dependencies`

Comment: How does your bundles.json look like? You have to include it in the bundles file. Did you do that?

Comment: It is not that the chart is not working or anything. Everything works fine. But I don't understand why I get the errors.

@kabaehr It is not an Aurelia plugin to add it like this.

Comment: @chrisdennig: I have added it to a vendor.js file:
>!


    "dist/vendor": {
      "includes": [
        "chart.js"

      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": true,
        "rev": false
      }

Comment: It don´t need to be a aurelia plugin. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508480/how-to-import-ion-rangeslider-in-aurelia/36560467#36560467.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you need to install `chart.js` with a "global" override:

```
jspm install npm:chartjs -o "{format: 'global'}"
```

But, actually, your best option is to use [aurelia-chart](https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-chart), which is based on chart.js 2.x :)